# C# EventLog.WriteEntry fail for some strings but not for others

Tags: c#, event-log

Having problem to write on windows event log with c#.

```
public static void writeToEventLog(string msgGrid, string msgIntern, EventLogEntryType entryType)  
{  
    string grp = "Application"; // Fixed because cant create new but happy if bellow works.  
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(msgGrid)) { EventLog.CreateEventSource(msgGrid, grp); }  
    EventLog.WriteEntry(msgGrid, msgIntern, entryType);  
}
```

---

//  The folowing code dont put entry on event log:

```
string msgGrid = "pdtidtijejrnexhr";  
string msgIntern = "*-* [Dt:2013-10-31 11:41:10.00][digkufdufe:{[<2013-10-31 11:41:09> {jpdriskrt01} jpdriskrt01[172.22.3.70:57010]> [pdtidhry jrnecidr]]} : {}] >>#[eydshr:(rhrdhruiweirts.hrt.krt.krtjelr.jt.jpdrtjelkrhtw.<dnjr>b__1)]>>#[jpdrtjelkrhtw]\\[pdtidtijejrnexhr]\r\n";

writeToEventLog(msgGrid, msgIntern, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);
```

---

//  The folowing code works OK:

```
writeToEventLog("t1", "t2", EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);
```

There is some constraint about log content or size ?

Comment: Is it excepting? Are you running both snippets of code as the same user? (`CreateEventSource()` will only work with the req'd privs.)

Comment: When you say "fail", what do you mean?

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling No, its not excepting, executing both as same user from Visual Studio 2010 C# 4.0 debug. Executing Visual Studio with administrator user.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Fail mean the entry isnt there, no happens, no exception on execution, no log entry complaining about nothing, only is like i did nothing on fail case, on sucess case the entry is there.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, now i have the try/catch and no exception happens, put try/catch and a breakpoint on throw inside catch. One of many times I tried it before put the qustion here resulted on a fragment of message on event log one hour after, i cleaned event log and tried again and nothing.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, yes i removed braces instead as a test and the same problem. Forget to write on comment about it im sory.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling, Thanks i tried the long message with "t1" source and the entry is there now, really strange because "pdtidtijejrnexhr" and "t1" are arbitrary strings and never tried it on this machine, "t1" source comes with windows ?  Why "t1" exists and "pdtidtijejrnexhr" not, same problem as commented on my code using "Application" because cant create new but its enought to me, wondering why. Thanks for time, effort and help.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling cant mark comment as answer, if you write it as answer i will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your source ("pdtidtijejrnexhr") doesn't exist yet, but "t1" does, so that's why the other snippet of code is working. Also, you may have to double-up your braces (`{` and `}`), but I'm not positive on that one. (`{{` and `}}`, respectively).

I don't think "t1" comes with Windows by default.. I suspect that your code successfully created it at one point (maybe in combination with when you **weren't** using braces in a log message?)

Comment: Really the sucess case dont use braces, its make sense. Thanks again.